# Laravel date validation after_or_equal not working

Tags: laravel

I have two date fields **`start_date`** and **`end_date`** (in a format like 2021-02-25 10:24:44), I want to use this format only and want that **end_date** must be equal or greater than **start_date**, **`after_or_equal`** is not working in my case.

I am using

```
'start_date'=> 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
'end_date'=> 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after_or_equal:start_date',
```

But, even if I am giving a end_date bigger than start_date I am getting this message

**`The end date must be a date after or equal to start time.`**

The inputs were

```
"start_date" : "2021-01-01 10:30:50",
"end_date" : "2021-01-01 11:31:55",
```

Please help me, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your start_date and end_date can be null, not sure what will happen in that case. should you try removing nullable and see?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond : cant do that, because in some cases, start_date and end_date can be nullable. I only want that if someone inputs the dates, then only it will validate them.

Comment: It is just to see whether after_or_equal really not working or your input is incorrect.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond : Thanks, it's working fine without nullable, but I don't know why, it is not working with nullable in place.